# Android - Limit only one decimal point enter into a EditText

Tags: android, decimal, android-edittext

I need help to only allow one decimal point to be entered into a `EditText` view.  An example: I don't want `123.45.2` or `123..452` to be allowed.  Once one decimal point is entered, no more are allowed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Play around with this however you like it.

```
myEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true));
```

> Returns a DigitsKeyListener that
>   accepts the digits 0 through 9, plus
>   the minus sign (only at the beginning)
>   and/or decimal point (only one per
>   field) if specified.

Comment: `.123` still be allowed

Comment: Api requirements is level 26

Answer (score 10):

You can set it up in the xml layout:

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:inputType="numberDecimal"    
/>
```

Comment: and? you still can print a lot of dots

Answer (score 4):

There's flags you can set so you don't have to do what rochdev (no offense of course) posted.

```
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

This will only allow numbers to be entered and only one decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Set it in xml layout
`android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"`