# Android validating EditText decimal point "."

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I am doing some math on the values of two `EditText` fields, I want to have the following validations on them:

1. They are not empty.
2. They are valid to each other(if the first field was integer the second should be the same, if the first was decimal the second should be the same).

I cannot figure out how to validate the decimal values or specifically the decimal point.

I have tried this out, but it didn't work. My app just crashes.

```
    if (editText1.getText().toString().equals(".") || editText2.getText().toString().equals(".")) 
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

For decimal value you can use this:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextView) ;   

et.setInputType(0x00002002);
```

It will accept only decimal values.

[Another solution is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083960/android-limit-only-one-decimal-point-enter-into-a-edittext).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to set your input type to accept decimals and/or numbers.

You can set it up in the xml layout:

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"    
/>
```

Then you can just convert your EditText text to double:

```
double result = new Double(editText1.getText().toString());
```

or

```
double result = Double.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
```

This rocket science that you wroted is not needed anymore after that.

Comment: I already convert it to a double.  The problem occurs when you try to parse a . to a double.

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains() method to check if your string contains the argument you provided

```
if (textView1.getText().toString().contains(".") || textView2.getText().toString().contains(".")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether something is a valid value or not by trying to parse it with Float.parseFloat and seeing if it throws a NumberFormatException (via try/catch). If it does, then you know the input is invalid.

Btw, it's nice if you provide a visual cue to the user to inform them that the input is invalid. As opposed to waiting until the user presses the "calculate" button and only tell them then.

Comment: Easy solution!   I'll catch the exception.  I was under the impression that Java made you try/catch anything that could throw an exception.  Thank you very much!